# Landau identification

Tags: taylor-expansion

Calculate taylor series for $x\rightarrow +\infty$ at the higher order allowed by the approximation present in it.
$$
\sqrt{x^6+x^5-2x^3+O\left(x^2\right)}
$$

I made this:
$$
x^3\cdot\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{2}{x^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right)}
$$

And calculated $$\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{2}{x^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right)}$$ as $$(1+t)^{1/2}$$

The rest of my series is:
$$
o\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{2}{x^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right)\right)
$$

But I don't know how to simplify it! Could anybody help me?

Comment: i have changed just word simplify and not semplify